# PHP - Can't bcadd() string because of not removable blank space

Tags: php

### TL;DR

String which is coming from an array and has this format: `436,97 €` can't be trimmed to something like this `436.97`which is why It's not possible to add this string to another using `bcadd()`.

### Full Text

I am trying to add two strings, one I declared myself and that is initialized with `"0.00"` and another one that is coming from an array and has this format: `436,97 €` I tried several things but in the end the output of `bcadd()` is 0.00. What am I doing wrong there?
I tried to simplify my code for posting it here and it is working:

```
<?php
$totalToAdd = "0.00";
$amount = "436,97 €";
$amount = trim($amount, "€");
$amount = str_replace(",",".",$amount);
$amount = trim($amount," ");
$totalToAdd = bcadd($totalToAdd, $amount,2);
echo $totalToAdd;
?>
```

I have no idea why my actual code in the program isn't, but I'll include that too with comments:
First I initialize the variable then I call the function to increase/decrease depending on the value which is coming from an array. (this whole construct is inside a loop).
 There are a lot of if.. else blocks which I removed here to make it easier to read.

```
$totalToAdd = "0.00";
$totalToAdd = $this->_updateSubtotal($totalToAdd, $totalData['label'],$totalData['amount']);
```

this is the function which is getting called:

```
protected function _updateSubtotal($total, $label, $amount){

    $amount = trim($amount, "€");
    $amount = str_replace(",",".",$amount);
    $amount = trim($amount," ");


    $total = bcadd($total, $amount,2);
    return $total;

}
```

The return of the function is always `$total = 0`
I tried to trim the string in one step trying both of these commands:
    `trim($amount, " €");`
    `trim($amount, "\x20€");`
But the value for `$amount` is in both cases:
    `$amount = "436,97 "`
I tried substr() too:
     `substr($amount,0,-2);`
but that leads to:
     `$amount = "436,97 �"`
So i tried the trimming in 2 Steps but this is what happens:

```
$amount = trim($amount, "€");              ->    $amount = "436,97 "
$amount = str_replace(",",".",$amount);    ->    $amount = "436.97 "
$amount = trim($amount," ");               ->    $amount = "436.97 "
```

Maybe that's why bcadd() doesn't work?
How can I get rid of that blank space?

### Edit:

I changed my code the way that I don't call my function with the value of the array: `$totalData['amount']` directly but instead use an additional variable: $amount so the function call looks like this:
 
     `$totalToAdd = $this->_updateOwnSubtotal($totalToAdd, $totalData['label'],$amount);`
and write the amount from the array into `$amount`before. I tried these methods, which both didn't work:
    `$amount = $totalData['amount'];` & `$amount = "" . $totalData['amount'];`

Then I tried it without the array by directly writing a string into the variable: `$amount = "436,97 €"` which works perfectly.

So there must be some issue with the values in my array. They should be strings, and they are when I try is_string() or gettype().

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: if you did not test it on apache, where did you test it on?

Comment: What is the output if you just do `trim($amount);`?

Comment: @ Farhan Qasim
On phpfiddle.org like I wrote there.
Simplified code on the top -> phpfiddle.org -> Working
Code below that with function being called -> on apache stack -> not working (It's a Magento instance actually)

Comment: @RigssFolly: If I am not mistaking bcadd() is adding strings not numbers..
It's working on phpfiddle too though
Actually I tried to remove the € and replaced the "," with a "." I wrote that all in my question.

Comment: @Mickael Leger
The output stays the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with `mb_substr`:
`$amount = mb_substr($amount,0,-2, 'UTF-8');`
`Input: "436,97 €"   ->   Output: "436.97"`
And the bcadd() is finally working without the additional blank space.